# How to fit tableview to superview below navigation bar via storyboard autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want to create a scroll disabled tableview which will fill the view below navigation bar. Finally I've managed to do it but it's not the right way because I'm giving minus 64 margin (status bar + navigation bar) to tableview.

I'm assigning my constraints from storyboard. I've tried lots of other constraints with the table view like giving zero constraints from 4 sides or 
equal width + equal height + center horizontal + center vertical none of them worked.

What is the right way to solve this problem.

Screenshot from the storyboard are below.

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26238698/1682484.

Comment: thnx, they are already checked not working that way.

Comment: Yeap unchecking them worked. It's still confusing understand how auto layout works. After unchecking four of them I set zero margin to 4 sides which is the meaning full set of constraints. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to give +1 to that answer if it fixed your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it.

[image]

unchecking four of them and adding the constraints from image below worked as I wanted.

[image]

So I guess scroll disabled tableviews not working as expected with these four view controller options checked.

Answer (score 3):

As kerem keskin said, unchecking resolves the issue but you don't need to uncheck all four. Just need to uncheck Adjust Scroll View Inset.

Refer to this: [iOS 7 -- navigationController is setting the contentInset and ContentOffset of my UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924431/ios-7-navigationcontroller-is-setting-the-contentinset-and-contentoffset-of-m)